# How to build a native android library with thumb(no thumb-2)?

Tags: android, assembly, makefile, arm

I have already built a native .so for android, the Android.mk is like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libxxx
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := xxx.c
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But I found a problem: maybe the thumb-2 instructions will be used, for example b.w, and, some android device use ARMv6, ARMv6 has no b.w instruction, if this .so file loaded in these devices, will cause crashes.

So I want to know how to force the compiler just use thumb to build? Write something in Android.mk? Please help me, thank you!

Comment: what compiler?  normally -mthumb does it and DONT specify the arch or specify armv4t if you really have to specify an arch

Comment: github.com/dwelch67 I have many examples of building for bare metal with gnu and llvm tools for thumb only thumb+thumb2, etc.

Comment: The compiler is GCC...How to write "-mthumb" in Android.mk, I Googled but have no result...

Comment: Did you have this problem, or is it just an assumption? Android builds two variants of arm binaries, `armeabi` for ARMv5TE and `armeabi-v7a` for ARMv7. These two variants doesn't contain invalid instructions for their targets.

Comment: Reference: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/text/ANDROID-MK.text

Comment: Why should someone target armv6 these days where v7 is by far the most dominating architecture? You can easily dump the legacy v6 or below. Especially the legacy thumb will seriously cripple the performance. If you ABSOLUTELY have to remain compatible with the legacy ones, target for the v6 or v5e and stick to ARM which is much less pain.

Comment: I don't like v6, but the CRASH is unacceptable. Anyway, thank all!